# Mouse stuck on Input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have no idea how to ask this question, but here's problem:

[image]

I have this kind of search bar ^  and when you double click on it it shrinks and input is disappearing (`display: none`). But when it disappears
[image]

And I-beam cursor shows. So I can't click or double click on it anymore (for some reason)
I tried input.blur(); but because it's not focused it didn't work. I have no clue what to google to fixed. I tried some but there weren't any related answers.

HTML:

```
<div class="search-field">
    <input placeholder="Search" type="text">
    
    <img src="search.svg" title="Double Click to toggle">
    <img src="grip-lines.svg" alt="||" id="drag">
</div>
```

I use keyframes so I will how CSS too: (Edit: I will put more about css)

```
.search-field {
     position: absolute;
     width: 385px;
     width: 20%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 15px;
    left: 8%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px black solid;
  }
  input {
        height: 80%;
        width: 300px;
        outline: none;
        transition: .3s;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px black solid;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        background-color: #E4E9F7;
   }

  @keyframes openSearch {
    0% {
        width: 77px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 385px;
    }
  }
  @keyframes closeSearch {
    0% {
        width: 385px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 77px;
    }
  }

  .openedSearch {
      animation: openSearch 0.5s both;
  }
  .closedSearch {
      animation: closeSearch 0.5s both;
  }
```

JS:

```
    let searchState = true
    let toggleSearchState = () => {
    searchState = !searchState
    if (searchState == true) {
        searchField.className = 'search-field openedSearch'
        input.style.display = 'block'
       } else {
        searchField.className = 'search-field closedSearch'
        input.style.display = 'none'
      }
   }

searchBtn.addEventListener('dblclick', toggleSearchState)
```

Comment: based on the code you have here, everything seems to be [working](https://jsfiddle.net/cpL5jodg/). Can you show the css you left out?

Comment: sure I will edit it

Comment: do you have a drag event on the svg image?

Comment: yes on the second svg

Answer (score 0):

Since everything seems to be working fine on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpL5jodg/). The only thing left (that I couldn't test) is the SVG images and any code you attached to them.

As the id of the pipe image is drag, I am assuming you have attached a drag event on it. Also, if the size of the image is not set you may be overlapping, covering the entire `search-field` when the width is set too `77px`.

An easy solution would be to set the height and width of the `img` tag with the draggable event, so you can be sure it is not overlapping.